# What should be the solution of the following problem?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a new `React-Native` project but I am getting the following error stack trace:

```
C:\Users\MY HP\Desktop\MyProjects\ReactNative\project01>expo init RunAtleast
? Choose a template: expo-template-blank
√ Please enter a few initial configuration values.
  Read more: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/ · 100% completed
Extracting project files...
Customizing project...
Installing dependencies...
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.5 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/expo/react-native-maps.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MY HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-04T18_59_55_657Z-debug.log
Process exited with non-zero code: 1
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're probably working with an outdated install. I'm not familiar with expo, are you using their latest version?

Comment: Yes I am using the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with your installation of git under Windows. A quick search turned up this link: https://github.com/amplience/cms-javascript-sdk/issues/1

Perhaps you can find more ideas how to fix this following the discussion there?

Answer (score 0):

It has been solves as I used npm cache clear --force and reinstalled npm install -g expo-cli. And the problem gets solved..thanks to the stackovelflow community for such types of help..